# Display Hello, Angular! in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have written the following program to print `Hello, Angular!` but it does not work. Please guide.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore"  ng-init="person={text:'Hello, Angular!'>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><div>
    {{person.text}}
  </div></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Missin a bracket and a quote `}"` for the `ng-init` attribute value

Comment: You have a typo, your missing a closing `}"`. I'm voting to close this question as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

You need a closing brace and quote for the ng-init

```
ng-init="person={text:'Hello, Angular!'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
ng-init="person={text:'Hello, Angular!'>
```

with:

```
ng-init="person={text:'Hello, Angular!'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo mistake, replace your code with below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore"  ng-init="person={text:'Hello, Angular!'}>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><div>
    {{person.text}}
  </div></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the right bracet and the quote. See the example below.